# In WPF how can I get the rendered size of a control before it actually renders?

Tags: wpf, layout, resize, rendering, render

I'm doing custom rendering in a Decorator subclass.  Our rendering requires creating complex geometries which only neded to be re-created when the actual rendered size changes.  As such, I have moved the geometry creation into its own function called `UpdateGeometry` which creates, then freezes the geometry for use in `OnRender`.  This new function only needs to be called in response to a change in `ActualWidth` or `ActualHeight`.

Even better, it looks like we should be able to simply override `OnRenderSizeChanged`, which according to the documentation states...

> "When overridden in a derived class,
>   participates in rendering operations
>   that are directed by the layout
>   system. This method is invoked ***after
>   layout update, and before rendering***,
>   if the element's RenderSize has
>   changed as a result of layout update."

However, regardless if I'm using the override or listening to the property change notifications of `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`, my logging consistently shows `OnRender` as happening first!  Um... Wha??

To be sure it wasn't something I was doing in my code, I created a bare-bones test decorator subclass and added logging there, both on entry and exit to the overrides.  Here is the entire class...

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public class TestControl : Decorator
{

    protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnRender Entered");

        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        Console.WriteLine("OnRender Exited");
    }

    protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(System.Windows.SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnRenderSizeChanged Entered");

        base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);

        Console.WriteLine("OnRenderSizeChanged Exited");
    }

}
```

And as I feared... here is the output...

```
OnRender Entered
OnRender Exited
OnRenderSizeChanged Entered
OnRenderSizeChanged Exited
```

So what am I missing here?

More importantly, how can I get the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` values after the layout subsystem has done its job, but before the control is rendered so I can create the geometry before it's needed in the `OnRender` override?

My latest implementation overrides `ArrangeOverride` as the value that's passed in there is a size containing what the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` values ***should*** be after the core layout system takes into consideration `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` with values of 'Stretch', minimums and maximums, etc, but what they actually are depends on the value that's returned from that override so it's a little more complex than that.

Either way, I'm still wondering why the `OnRenderSizeChanged` call doesn't happen when it's supposed to.  Thoughts?

Mark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you should be able to get the correct size from [ArrangeOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride.aspx). This doesn't include things like Margin, but that probably shouldn't be taken into account. You could either use the size passed as a parameter as your "render" size or use the return value of the base.ArrangeOverride call.

EDIT:

The OnRender method is called from the Arrange method, after OnArrangeOverride is ultimately called. The OnRenderSizeChanged on the other hand is called from UpdateLayout, which is effectively dispatched to be executed all at once for a given section of the visual tree. This is why the OnRenderSizeChanged is called after the OnRender.

The documentation may refer to the "rendering" as in actually rendered to the screen, not when OnRender is called. WPF can cache the rendering instructions for a given element and execute them when needed. So the fact that OnRender is called before OnRenderSizeChanged, doesn't mean it's actual rendering instructions are committed to the screen at that time.

You can modify your OnRenderSizeChanged to force OnRender to be called again using:

```
protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(System.Windows.SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnRenderSizeChanged Entered");

    base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
    this.InvalidateVisual();

    Console.WriteLine("OnRenderSizeChanged Exited");
}
```

You may also want to skip your OnRender code if RenderSize is "0,0".

Comment: Yeah... that's what I had just edited at the bottom of my description above as what we're currently doing as a 'work-around', but that still doesn't explain the OnRenderSizeChanged override not working as the documentation says.  Also, the *only* thing I think that doesn't take into consideration is Margin since that's outside of what gets rendered anyway.  Do you know of any other things that aren't taken into consideration?

Comment: @MarquelV - Updated my answer based on your comments.

Comment: Looks like just sticking with the ArrangeOverride is what I need to do.  You got the answer! :)